# GROUP BY with aggregate SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have  a complex query which I have dumped into a temp table.

Within this data set I have different types of deals: Movies, COD, Features, Other.

All the deals that are COD and Others and have a totalrev_YTD BETWEEN 10K and 15K should be summed into a single line with the deal name as "TOTAL COD"
other wise it should have it's own line.

How would I do this. I can't seem to do `GROUP BY` using `SUM(totalrev_YTD)` BETWEEN 10 and 15k.

Can anyone please help:

```
SELECT 
    location, locationid, dealtype,
    (CASE 
        WHEN dealtype = 'OTHER (COD, ETC)' and totalrev_YTD BETWEEN 10000 AND 15000 
           THEN 'OTHER (COD, ETC)'
        ELSE deal
    END) as deal,
    rental_PW, rental_MTD, rental_QTD, rental_YTD,
    sales_PW, sales_MTD, sales_QTD, sales_YTD,
    otherrev_PW, otherrev_MTD, otherrev_QTD, otherrev_YTD,
    totalrev_PW, totalrev_MTD, totalrev_QTD, totalrev_YTD
FROM 
    #temp_rev t1
WHERE 
    dealtype = 'OTHER (COD, ETC)'
GROUP BY 
    (CASE 
        WHEN dealtype = 'OTHER (COD, ETC)' and totalrev_YTD BETWEEN 10000 AND 15000 
           THEN 'OTHER (COD, ETC)'
        ELSE deal
    END),
    location, locationid, dealtype,
    rental_PW, rental_MTD, rental_QTD, rental_YTD,
    sales_PW, sales_MTD, sales_QTD, sales_YTD,
    otherrev_PW, otherrev_MTD, otherrev_QTD, otherrev_YTD,
    totalrev_PW, totalrev_MTD, totalrev_QTD, totalrev_YTD
```

An example of this would be I have 10 COD, OTHER deals. Where 1 of the deal has a `totalrev_YTD` > 15K. In this case that should appear with its own line and the other should just be aggregated.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: when you say you can't are you getting an error?  The use of case statement in group by is valid, but you left in the original column dealtype in the group by and select.  The same case statement should be in select.  Also with all of those columns you probably are not aggregating how you really want to.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `GROUP BY` is good, you just need it to be on less columns, and then you aggregate (with `SUM`) all the numbers that should be, well, summed.

In the cases where it is a "single-line" deal, the query will just sum that one row, which is totally ok.

Example:

```
SELECT location, locationid, dealtype
, (CASE WHEN dealtype = 'OTHER (COD, ETC)' and totalrev_YTD BETWEEN 10000 AND 15000 THEN 'OTHER (COD, ETC)'
    ELSE deal
    END
  ) as deal,
sum(rental_PW) as rental_PW,
sum(rental_MTD) as rental_MTD,
..., -- insert other summed columns here
sum(totalrev_YTD) as totalrev_YTD

FROM #temp_rev t1
WHERE dealtype ='OTHER (COD, ETC)'

GROUP BY 
(CASE WHEN dealtype = 'OTHER (COD, ETC)' and totalrev_YTD BETWEEN 10000 AND 15000 THEN 'OTHER (COD, ETC)'
    ELSE deal
    END
  ) ,
location, locationid, dealtype
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It should only return 2 rows. One deal which has totalrev_YTD > 15K and another row with the sum of everything else. But it returns 150 rows for each deal...

Comment: @a415 you said if dealtype is "OTHER (COD, ETC)" and YTD between 10K and 15K then sum, and "other wise it should have it's own line".  So, 1 row for all the deals you're lumping together, and what is the grouping criteria for the remaining rows?  I assumed 1 row per location / locationid / dealtype / deal combination.  Are you saying you want 1 summary row for the given criteria and 1 row for everything else, for a total of 2 rows?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding...